# Read anchor from URL in ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

How i can read anchor from URL, in Controller action.

Example URL: www.site.com/some-action#**anchor-what-i-want-read**

```
public ActionResult SomeAction()
{
    // Here i want read the anchor
}
```

Reason for this:
I need set og:image for facebook, by anchor tag. Because i have too many item on page. So automatic facebook image fetching not working. And I using anchor for direct navigation to product on page.

**Final solution:**

I add optional URL paramter into link www.site.com/some-action/**id**, so I can by this parameter resolve the FB og:image, and I use JS pro navigation into anchor by that parameter form URL.

Comment: That value doesn't get passed to the server automatically.  You'll have to pass it manually with some JavaScript and/or hidden form fields, etc.  What are you actually trying to accomplish?  How do you get to this action method and what information does it need?  Chances are there's a much better way to achieve the end goal without going this route.

Comment: What are you trying to do ? There should be a better way

Comment: I add reason for this solution

Comment: @David I cant pass any form's field, I need to be working just with GET request :/

Comment: @JinDave: You'll need to add the value to the query string, then.  Something like: `www.site.com/some-action?key=value`  Then you'd read it in the action method as a method parameter: `public ActionResult SomeAction(string key)`  Query string values (key/value pairs, specifically) are how data is sent via a GET request.

Comment: Is it not present when you do `Request.Url`?

Comment: @mattytommo No it isn't

Comment: It wouldn't be present in `Request.Url` because it's not part of the URL being requested of the server.  The `#anchor-what-i-want-read` notation is used entirely client-side.  The server resource is `www.site.com/some-action`.  The way to pass values to the server resource in a GET request is by query string parameters.

Answer (score 0):

in my project all these actions are loading with $.ajax(). something like this:

```
var href = window.location.href;
href = href.substr(0, href.indexOf('#'));
href += (href.indexOf("?") == -1 ? "?" : "&") + "hashvalue=" + window.location.hash.substr(1);
$.ajax({
 url: href,
 success: function(response){
  // write to content holder this response
 }
});
```

to tell the truth, all my actions are calling by http://my.site.com/#!controllername/actionname